# white text on white background image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I've image and label over it. Images are of multiple color and I would like to add text label of white color. Is there anyway I can make the label text standout even if background image is white color?

I tried lowering alpha value for the background image, it gives little effect but label text not standing out clearly unless alpha value for background image is too low.

Comment: Give the label a background color so its text is visible.

Comment: I thought about it but for better look, I want to have transparent background for the text label

Comment: Bordered type or a drop shadow are usual solutions to this problem.

Comment: @PandurangYachwad So set the alpha on the `UIColor` value for the background color.

Comment: I like the suggestion from @Sarcoma. Using an NSAttributedString you can give the text a border and/or shadow. Or just use the label to add the shadow.

Comment: @rmaddy adding background color for the label is distracting, so looking for something else

Comment: @matt I tried highlighting the text and adding shadow, this gives little clear text. But also same time it's not standing out. If nothing else, I may have to continue with this

Comment: Okay, so your question is no longer a programming question. You know, from a programming point of view, what all the options are. Now it's just a question of what looks good to you. This is not the forum to debate that. Voting to close.

Comment: @matt not trying to debate buddy, trying to see is there any alternative to do it better way. If someone knows to do it better, it's beneficial for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your label field with a shadow on it.

Comment: Yes, adding shadow is looking better, trying to see is there alternate way which will make the text standout.